# Setting null to PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, null, prepared-statement

The typical situation: we have some nullable column with type `Integer` and it might be both `null` or some `int` value. So we use the following:

```
private static void setIntOrNull(PreparedStatement stmt, int col, Integer i)
    throws SQLException
    {
        if (i == null)
            stmt.setNull(col, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
        else
            stmt.setInt(col, i);
    }
```

But for me this case is kind of bad practise - to change the external object within internal void method (reffering to [Robert Martin's "Clean Code"](http://www.tud.ttu.ee/material/kallik/JOOP/Clean_Code_-_A_Handbook_of_Agile_Software_Craftsmanship.pdf) Chapter 17: Smells and Heuristics, Functions, F2). I try to avoid such situation, but this time I just could not find a better solution. Maybe someone could help me with one?

Comment: +1. I've never understood why there was no `setInteger(int position, Integer valueOrNull)` method in PreparedStatement. And why there was no `Integer getNullableInteger(int position)` in ResultSet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's particularly bad, really. Let's see:

- It's `void`, so it *must* have side-effects, or be useless
- It's static, so it can't have any effect on "the object it's called" on; there isn't one!

So *either* the side-effect is going to be a global one (e.g. external such as a file system, internal such as static variable, or temporal e.g. sleeping) *or* it will affect one of the objects referred to by the parameters.

The `int` isn't an object, `Integer` objects are immutable, so the *only* thing it can be affecting is the `PreparedStatement`. As one of the purposes of prepared statements is to collect parameter data, it seems entirely reasonable that the method will do so. The method name makes this even clearer - where else is it going to "set" an int or null, if not on the prepared statement?

Basically: don't worry :)

You *may* want to make this even clearer by moving it to a public "helper" class such as `PreparedStatementHelper` - that makes it potentially obvious that really you'd like these methods to be on `PreparedStatement`, but they're not so you've got to have a static method instead to *act on* a `PreparedStatement`.

One alternative would be to create your own *wrapper* class which would maintain a `PreparedStatement` itself, and have an instance `setIntOrNull` method... but in the long run I believe that would be a lot more complicated, for little benefit.